# PHP - list() query not working

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the code below when $entry = miami.com, I get the following error message:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #&*+ WHERE `site`
LIKE 'miami.com':You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use
near '' at line 1
```

It looks like I'm not correctly defining $table. Any ideas how I could do that?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM feather") 
or die(mysql_error()); 


while(list($table)= mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  $sqlA = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE `site` LIKE '$entry'";
  $resA = mysql_query($sqlA) or die("$sqlA:".mysql_error());
  list($isThere) = mysql_fetch_row($resA);
  if ($isThere)
  {
     $table_list[] = $table;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's $table defined? What is $table?

Comment: Let's step back for a second. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well,

I'm trying to show a list of all tables in the database "feather" that contain $entry.

Comment: I'm smelling sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Also, I want the tables to contain $entry in the column called "site."

Comment: It looks loke your "show tables" query returns garbage. Can you post the output of the query?

Comment: Actually, I recently recalled that my very first table name is indeed "#&*+."  I added it deliberately during development.

Comment: I'm wondering how you came to the conclusion that list() is your problem.

Comment: I thought that $table was not defined correctly, and it first appears as list($table).

I thought that #&*+ was part of an error statement.  I had forgotten that I had it as a table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it were me debugging that i would see what

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_row($result));
```

outputs

Comment: what if you put ` around the table name
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$table` ...

I tried and i cant even create a table named #&*+

Comment: I just remembered that my first table name is called #&*+.  I thought that was an error.

I added this odd table name during development.

Comment: what happens if you rename/remove that table?

Comment: I tried putting ` around $table, and no error message.  I'll print a few things out to see if you solved my problem.

Comment: Quick question: how would I print or echo $table_list[]?

Comment: In any event, I think you solved my problem: it was the back-ticks.

Comment: foreach($table_list as $t){echo "$t<br>"}

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the [list-language construct](http://se.php.net/list) incorrectly:

> **Description**
>
> ```
> void list ( mixed $varname [, mixed $... ] )
> ```
>
> Like [array()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php), this is not really a function, but a language construct. **list()** is used to > assign a list of variables in one operation.

Example:

```
$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');

// Listing all the variables
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";
```

Now, what you are trying to do is to fetch dynamic table-names (it seems). You do not need to use the list-function, since you can [access the result as an array](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) (you can define the appropriate indexes of the array that you are interested in and only assign them, but I think array access is much clearer):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $sqlA = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${row['table']} WHERE `site` LIKE '$entry'";
  [...]
}
```

I am a bit curious though, do ALL the tables in your database *feather* have a column named *site*? Otherwise this query will fail, no matter how you format or refactor your code.

Comment: Yes, all the tables have a column named "site."  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: And you are also connected to the database feather?

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to feather.  I tried this code:




while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $sqlA = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${row['table']} WHERE `site` LIKE '$entry'";
  $resA = mysql_query($sqlA) or die("$sqlA:".mysql_error());
  list($isThere) = mysql_fetch_row($resA);
  if ($isThere)
  {
     $table_list[] = $table;
  }
}

and I got this error:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WHERE `site` LIKE 'miami.com':You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `site` LIKE 'miami.com'' at line 1

Comment: oh, you have to change 'table' into the correct index. do a var_dump($row); exit; before the sql and print the result

Answer (score 1):

> Actually, I recently recalled that my
>   very first table name is indeed
>   "#&*+." I added it deliberately during
>   development

And you're wondering why your SQL fails? :)

**Quote your table name** because this one is by far not a table name that can be used literally.

Something like

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \"$table\" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i think need to add MYSQL_ASSOC
to line that do the loop

mysql_fetch_row($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)

the default is :  MYSQL_BOTH

what mean that in the php loop you get the entry of the table name ,
and the entry of index like 0,1,2,...

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but when I do that, I get this error:

Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_fetch_row()

Comment: sorry i mistake i think u use fetch_array , u use fetch_row that is not problem

Comment: but try to do this :
while ($tmp_tbl = mysql_fetch_array( $res_tbl ))
 {
  $curr_tbl = $tmp_tbl[0];
}

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your SHOW TABLES query is returning garbage. I was able to reproduce your problem by copying an existing table_name.frm to #&@.frm in the data folder for a local database. Make sure your database is not corrupt (meaning, try repair): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: Actually, my very first table name is called #&*+.  During development, I added it on purpose to see if it would work

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM feather") or die(mysql_error()); 

while($table_row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  $table = $table_row[0];
  $sqlA = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `" . mysql_escape_string($table) . "` WHERE `site` LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($entry) . "'";
  $resA = mysql_query($sqlA) or die("$sqlA:".mysql_error());
  $isThere_row = mysql_fetch_row($resA);
  $isThere = $isThere_row[0];
  if ($isThere)
  {
     $table_list[] = $table;
  }
}
```

NOTE: variables inside your sql should be escaped. I don't use mySQL but I assume mysql_escape_string should work. There is another function, mysql_real_escape_string, that might be more appropropriate. You may want to read the docs for that.